# make list consists of the same item

Tags: prolog

`makeList(N, Item, List)` which given a (non-negative) integer `N` and item `Item` will construct a list `List` of `N` elements each of which is `Item`. For example, `makeList(5, a, List)` should return `List = [a,a,a,a,a]`.

```
make_List(0,Item,[]).
make_List(N,Item,List):-N>1,N1 is N-1,make_List(N1,Item,[Item|List]).
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why did you delete the code you had in your question? Please put it back.

Comment: Don't be sorry ;-) the only thing is that your code seems okay to me. In the question below I just showed a cleaner, easier way to write the predicate so that it is more general than the solution you have.

Comment: just correct the guard to `N>=1`

Comment: @CapelliC that's problem one, but there is a second. :) see my answer

Comment: @CapelliC ... or `N > 0` ;-)

Comment: @User9213 if you do that, `make_list(5, _, L), length(L, 5)` will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to declare that the list has that length, and that every element *unifies* with your item:

```
makeList(N, Item, List) :-
    length(List, N),
    maplist(=(Item), List).
```

Here it is with SWI-Prolog:

```
$ swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.10-56-g1631e38f2-DIRTY)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- [user].
|: makeList(N, Item, List) :-
|:     length(List, N),
|:     maplist(=(Item), List).
|: ^D% user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- makeList(5, a, List).
List = [a, a, a, a, a].
```

and with GNU-Prolog:

```
$ gprolog
GNU Prolog 1.4.5 (64 bits)
Compiled Jul 15 2018, 03:47:56 with gcc
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2018 Daniel Diaz
| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
makeList(N, Item, List) :-
    length(List, N),
    maplist(=(Item), List).

user compiled, 3 lines read - 450 bytes written, 9422 ms

(5 ms) yes
| ?- makeList(5, a, List).

List = [a,a,a,a,a]

yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Prolog! You're actually very close! You have two problems in your code. The first is that `N>1` will fail on 1, but 1 will not have succeeded in your other `make_List(0, ...` clause. You meant to say `N >= 1`.

Your second problem is that you are modifying the list as you are passing it into the recursive steps, but you have no way to get it back out from the innermost level. What you need to do instead is modify it on the way *out*, which you do by changing the parameter on the left side of the `:-`, like this:

```
make_List(0, Item, []).
make_List(N, Item, [Item|List]) :- N>=1, N1 is N-1, make_List(N1, Item, List).
```

In the future, to help find these kinds of problems, try invoking your code with `trace, make_List(5, a, X).` You will see steps in the output that can help you figure out some of these problems--at least the N>1 problem was very easy to spot this way.

Comment: @zhao my contact info is in my profile, but I would recommend you ask here since you get the benefit of faster response and more insight from the community. I am not an expert, but experts do answer questions here, from time to time.